# Local estimate for a $C^1$ map with negative definite Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $U$ be an open set in ${\Bbb R^n}$ and $f=(f^1,\cdots,f^n):U\to{\Bbb R^n}$ be $C^1$. Suppose $f'(x_0)$ is negative definite for some $x_0\in U$. Show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that for any $y_1,\cdots, y_n\in V$
>   $$
> \xi\cdot A\xi\leq -\epsilon|\xi|^2
> $$
>   for all $\xi\in{\Bbb R^n}$ where
>   $$
> A=\left(
> \begin{matrix}
> \nabla f^1(y_1)\\
> \nabla f^2(y_2)\\
> \vdots\\
> \nabla f^n(y_n)
> \end{matrix}
> \right).
> $$

---

If $y_1=\cdots=y_n=x_0$, then $A=f'(x_0)$ and the inequality is basically saying $A+\epsilon I_n$ is negative semi-definite. Here are my **questions**:

- If this case (which looks simpler) can be shown (I don't see how though), does it help the general cases?
- What does $A$ generally mean and how can the general cases be done?

Comment: I'm bothered here by the term negative definite. Do we have any reason to assume that $f'(x_0)$ is a symmetric linear map?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, you are right. I found this problem from some qualifying exam on this [list](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/270467/9464), which is from MSE. I  guess it is sort of an abuse of the term "negative definite" while it means $\xi\cdot A\xi<0$ for all nonzero $\xi\in{\Bbb R^n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try proving by contradiction, and a diagonal argument. $A$ is essentially an approximation to $f'(x_0).$ Suppose the contrary of the problem, and observe that for each $m \in \mathbb{N},$ we see that for $\epsilon_m = 1/m, V_m = B(x_0,\epsilon_m),$ there exist points $y^{(m)}_1, \cdots y^{(m)}_n,$ and $\xi^{(m)} \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1},$ such that

$$
\xi^{(m)} \cdot A^{(m)} \xi^{(m)} \geq -\epsilon_n.
$$
Now use the compactness of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, and observe $A^{(m)} \to f'(x_0),$ through possibly a subsequence. This contradicts negative definiteness of $f'(x_0).$

$A^{(m)}$ really has the obvious meaning!
Where did you find this problem?

Comment: Do you mean $B(x_0, \epsilon_m)$ in the third line?

Comment: And $S^{m-1}$ should be $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: I've corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a geometric interpretation for $A$. Maybe it has some use in a context not present in the question. Or it could be just something made up for an exercise. Right now I think of $A$ as "perturbed Jacobian".

The key point is simple:  strict inequalities, applied to continuous functions, yield open sets. But one  has to carefully set up the functions and inequalities to get the desired result.

In this case, I would define a map $F:U^n\times S^{n-1}\to\mathbb R$ as follows: 
$$F(y_1,\dots,y_n,\xi) = \xi \cdot A(y_1\dots,y_n)\xi$$
with $A$ as in your question. (Note that $U^n$ is the Cartesian product of $n$ copies of $U$, while $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere). Since  $F$ is continuous, the set $\{F<-\epsilon\}$ is open in $U^n\times S^{n-1}$ for every $\epsilon$. For each $\xi\in S^{n-1}$ there is $\epsilon_\xi>0$ for which this set contains $ (x_0,\dots,x_0,\xi)$, hence it contains a neighborhood of this set. Such a neighborhood contains s product-type neighborhood $V_\xi^n\times W_\xi$ where $V_\xi$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ in $\mathbb R^n$  and $W_\xi$ is a neighborhood of $\xi$ in $S^{n-1}$. From the open cover
$$\{(x_0,\dots,x_0)\}\times S^{n-1}\subset \bigcup_{\xi\in S^{n-1}}V_\xi^n\times W_\xi$$
you can choose a finite subcover. Intersect $V_\xi$ over the members of this subcover, take the minimum of $\epsilon_\xi$, and you are done.

Although it's true  that sequences + contradiction, as in Raghav's answer, is a quicker way.